# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime (tensorflow compatibility for MrCNN implementation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I am currently running the MRCnn demo notebook file as I want to implement segmentation. I have uploaded the code snippets to my jupiter notebook which is connected to my ec2 instance on AWS. I am having trouble finding which version of TensorFlow and Keras is compatible with the Mrcnn model by Matterhorn. I have been installing various versions of TensorFlow and keras but I am not able to get the exact one that is compatible. Can someone guide me?  I am getting the following error
My current tensorflow version is - 1.3.0 (gpu)
Keras version - 2.0.8

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ebe7095df7bb> in <module>
     13 # Import Mask RCNN
     14 sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
---> 15 from mrcnn import utils
     16 import mrcnn.model as modellib
     17 from mrcnn import visualize

~/MyNotebooks/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/utils.py in <module>
     14 import random
     15 import numpy as np
---> 16 import tensorflow as tf
     17 import scipy
     18 import skimage.color

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53 
     54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

The code snippet that I executedis as follows

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../")

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
# Import COCO config
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "samples/coco/"))  # To find local version
import coco

%matplotlib inline 

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

# Directory of images to run detection on
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "images")
```